# How to find the index position of a radio button selected in a PDF Acrofield using iText Java

Tags: java, pdf, radio-button, itext, acrofields

```java
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfbytes);
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();
Set <String> fields = acroFields.getFields().keySet();
for (String field:fields) {
    if (AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_RADIOBUTTON == acroFields.getFieldType(field)) {
        String fieldId = acroFields.getField(field);
        List<AcroFields.FieldPosition> positions = acroFields.getFieldPostions(field);
        System.out.println("List size : " + positions.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
            Rectangle rect = acroFields.getFieldPositions(field).get(i).position;
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to find and iterate the list of position under a radio group.

I would like to know the index of the radio button that is selected in order to find its absolute position.

Comment: *"I would like to know the index of the radio button that is selected"* - which index do you mean? And what do you mean by "selected".

Answer (score 0):

The the following code should provide you with directions. Please note that it might be possible that no radiobutton is checked. Also you have to do the error handling etc...

```
for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {

    Item fieldItem = acroFields.getFieldItem(field);
    PdfDictionary dict = entry.getValue().getWidget(i);
    PdfName as = dict.getAsName(PdfName.AS);
    if(as==null){
      //handle/throw error if AS key is not set and there are one or more  subdictionaries!
    }
    String asValue = PdfName.decodeName(as.toString());
    if("Off".equalsIgnoreCase(asValue)){
       System.out.println("not checked");
    } 
    else{
       System.out.println("Checked");
       //do what you need to do
    }
}
```